# Quest'anno sembra davvero *nera* vs. Quest'anno sembra davvero *nero*

Tags: gender

> - Quest'anno sembra davvero *nera* per il commercio prenatalizio, ciò quantomeno è ciò che appare osservando negozi vuoti e strade semideserte, .
> - Quest'anno sembra davvero *nero* per il commercio prenatalizio, ciò quantomeno è ciò che appare osservando negozi vuoti e strade semideserte, .

*nero*, che preferisco, e *nera* sembrano entrambi corretti lì, c'è qualcuno che spiega perché?

Answer (score 18):

Sono entrambe corrette.

> - Nel primo caso il soggetto sottinteso di "nera", ossia poco favorevole, è la situazione, la condizione (per il commercio natalizio).
> - Nel secondo caso "nero" ossia negativo, si riferisce all'anno.